Message does not get decrypted in Python with LightPHE
for the following code in which I am trying to test homomorphic algorithms I have some troubles, basically the message which is displayed in my GUI does not get decrypted even though I am trying to decrypt it. Basically I am not even sure if what it does is correct because I cannot see the output decrypted
Here is my code:

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import csv
import random
import time
from lightphe import LightPHE

def generate_and_write_transactions(filename, num_transactions):
    transactions = []
    for _ in range(num_transactions):
        amount_received = round(random.uniform(10, 500), 2)  
        transactions.append(("Deposit", amount_received))
    
    with open(filename, "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow(["Transaction Type", "Amount"])
        csvwriter.writerows(transactions)

def compute_total_amount():
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        filename = "transaction_history.csv"
        total_amount = 0
        
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            next(reader)  # Skip header row
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] == 'Deposit':
                    total_amount += float(row[1])
        
        end_time = time.time()
        result_label.config(text=f"Total amount (traditional computation): ${total_amount:.2f}\nTime taken: {end_time - start_time:.6f} seconds")
    except Exception as e:
        result_label.config(text="Error: " + str(e))

def compute_total_amount_homomorphic():
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        filename = "transaction_history.csv"

        cs = LightPHE(algorithm_name="Paillier")
        
        encrypted_values = []  

        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            next(reader)  
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] == 'Deposit':
                    encrypted_amount = cs.encrypt(plaintext=float(row[1]))
                    encrypted_values.append(encrypted_amount)
        
        total_sum = sum(cs.decrypt(encrypted_amount) for encrypted_amount in encrypted_values)

        total_encrypted_sum = cs.encrypt(plaintext=total_sum)
        
        end_time = time.time()
        
        result_text = f"Total amount (homomorphic encryption): ${total_sum:.2f}\nTime taken: {end_time - start_time:.6f} seconds"
        result_label.config(text=result_text)
    except Exception as e:
        result_label.config(text="Error: " + str(e))

generate_and_write_transactions("transaction_history.csv", 10)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bank Account testing")

root.geometry("400x300") 

compute_button = tk.Button(root, text="Compute Total Amount (Traditional)", command=compute_total_amount)
compute_button.pack(pady=5)

compute_homomorphic_button = tk.Button(root, text="Compute Total Amount (Homomorphic)", command=compute_total_amount_homomorphic)
compute_homomorphic_button.pack(pady=5)

result_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
result_label.pack()

root.mainloop()

I want it to display the message with the correct total amount

Does this help missing brace bracket without using append? total_sum = [sum(cs.decrypt(encrypted_amount) for encrypted_amount in encrypted_values)]

To us the homomorphic encryption correct, you should first sum it up, and then decrypt the summed values like this:
total_sum = sum(encrypted_values)
total_sum_decrypted = cs.decrypt(total_sum)

